# How to fix "DiscardVirtualMemory could not be located" when installing GitHub Desktop?

Tags: windows-7, github-desktop

I am just trying to install GitHub  Desktop on my Windows 7 PC. But it's saying "the procedure entry point DiscardVirtualMemory could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll."

How can I resolve this error?

At first I installed Windows6.1-KB2758857-x64 to get over this problem, but that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: That function exists only on Windows 8.1/Windows Server 2012, and up. Why are you using such an old version?

Comment: Github Desktop does not support Windows 7.

Comment: Windows 7 hasn't been supported since the *very start* of 2020. You really need to upgrade your operating system at this point. Microsoft were literally giving away Windows 10 to home users 4/5 years ago. The reason things aren't working is because of *your* environment, not the application.

Comment: Just like the way people have the right to enjoy vinyl records and cassette tapes no matter what year it is, people have the right to use their favourite OS no matter what year it is.

Comment: "Microsoft were literally giving away Windows 10 to home users" - Win10 was so crappy that for the first time in history that had to give it away for free!

Comment: @ThomA The reason things aren't working is that the application authors deliberately broke backwards compatibility. There are millions of home users out there who may *never* upgrade. I was taught in 1976 about backwards compatibility, and specifically that 'there is always someone still running version 1.' Application developers need to realize this, and that backwards compatibility isn't even a technical issue, it is a marketing issue.

Comment: It's 2024, *not* 1976, @user207421 . Users can *easily* update their software with an internet connection. As for supporting Windows 7 still, it makes little sense to do so. Windows 7 stopped getting updates in 2024, and does *not* support many feature in more recent versions of Windows. If applications want to make use of those features, then they can't support those older versions any more. Making sure that your application works on an OS that hasn't had updates in over 3 years makes little sense. By your stance, you would expend GitHub Desktop to be able to be run on Windows 1...

Comment: If, however, you were complaining about the short time that some companies support products, I would be on your side (for example many mobile phones only getting updates for 2-3 years after release date). 10+ years of support, however, is more than reasonable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like version 3.2.4 is smart enough to handle the situation.

[image]

Uninstall the version of GithubDesktop that is "TOO NEW" for Windows 7.
Then install v3.2.4

To find the installer go to,
https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/17209#issuecomment-1677203754